# Using an SVG as a background for a specific portion of a website

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend

I'm trying to use an SVG as a background for a specific section on a website I'm creating, but I'm finding it difficult. The main problem I'm having is the SVG covers the text, but in the image, I'll link below the SVG is behind the text.

This is [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTIdu.jpg)

This is some code I wrote which didn't work.

```
.icons_and_text {  
  margin-top: 100px;  
  position: relative;  
 }  

.icons_and_text::before {  
  content: '';  
  background-image: url('./images/bg-curvy-desktop.svg');  
  background-size: cover;  
  position: absolute;  
  top: -600px;  
  left: 10;  
  height: 400px;  
  width: 100%;  
 }
```

I'm looking for answers which would enable me to solve the problem on my own next time, thank you.

Comment: change class name this type of classes name is not working so change `.icons\_and\_text` to `.icons_and_text` and then try

Comment: Sorry the class name is right, seems it was an error while copying.

Comment: brother this type of class, not pic any style

Comment: I edited it, in my code the class name is the correct one. While copying it to StackOverflow it added the /

Comment: okay! can you show your code in snippet or codepan

Comment: I created a  GitHub page for that: https://carrickkv2.github.io/Fylo-dark/

Still, the relevant portion was was I posted in the question above.

Comment: I have posted the answer check and let me if not working

Answer (score 1):

Hope it works for you

```
header .container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Because the background is dark that just makes the element totally disappear. Really thought z-index would also work. They are not the same color though, just slight differences in shades, enough to appear. I'll post the whole header code in a code pen, together with the svg link.

Comment: Codepen link: https://codepen.io/carrickkv2/pen/gOMBmWo

SVG link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w5ZPaiXdspRFwU_BBtEUAgxs-Z-feo2p/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what's the issue with above answer ?

Comment: z-index hides the element. Still, I think I got a solution, so I'll paste it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, although it's not exactly what I want. What I want is a perfect way to position the image.

```
header.header {
    background-color: hsl(217, 28%, 15%);
    background-image: url(../images/bg-curvy-desktop.svg);
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 23rem;
}
```